# Adding selector to navigationbar button programmatically

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, ios, uinavigationcontroller

Hey, I am trying to add a selector to a button in my navigationbar programmatically and I can't seem to find out why it doesn't work at all. Here is the code I got:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(showWithLabel)];
```

Am I doing this correctly and is there anything else I should do?

EDIT: I found out that the button was `nil`, I don't understand as it is connected to `rightBarButton` outlet.

EDIT(Again): I found out that the navigationitem is nil, any idea where is the problem then?

Comment: check whether the rightBarButtonItem is nil.

Comment: It was nil indeed, I don't have idea why as it is connected as rightbarbutton outlet ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem ...` ?

Answer (score 2):

I use to do that like this and works fine

```
    presetButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:framePresetButton];
    UIImage *presetBtnBG = [[[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment_tools.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12.0 topCapHeight:0.0] retain];


    [presetButton setImage:presetBtnBG forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    presetButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:presetButton];
    [presetButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loadPreset) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = presetButtonItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

So you say `self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` is `nil`, but `rightBarButtonItem` is hooked up in IB.

There are two reasons why this could be:

1. You haven't loaded your nib yet. (From what little I know of UIViewController, this seems unlikely.)
2. `navigationItem`, `navigationController`, or `self` is `nil`.

Remember that property access expressions are really message expressions. If, say, `self.navigationController` is `nil`, then sending it the `navigationItem` message will return `nil`. If, one way or the other, `self.navigationController.navigationItem` is `nil`, then asking it for its `rightBarButtonItem` will return `nil`.

Check every one of those sub-expressions—`self`, `self.navigationController`, and `self.navigationController.navigationItem`—and see which one is `nil`. Then, fix that one.

Comment: Ok I found out that the navigation item is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a colon after your selector name, like this:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(showWithLabel:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set also a target which will receive an action (I think you'll use 'self'):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(showWithLabel)];
[self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTarget:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to create rightBarButtonItem programmatically in viewDidLoad method:

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editEventQuestion)]; 
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem;
[rightBarButtonItem release];
```